# Using jQuery to insert full html page in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am trying to create a webpage including an iframe where the iframe has customizable content. Its an API project.
My main issue is not how to manage appending content to an iframe using jQuery, but in this case I have an empty iframe where I want to insert a full webpage into it. The code for the webpage going into the iframe is received using a .post function where I in return get the full webpage in the data variable. 
I can't manage to insert the full code, which include local javascript with important javascript libraries. It is as if it doesn't execute the code inside the iframe. The code is inserted but all the main html/body etc tags are deleted from the code passed in data variable, which prevents various javascript code from working.
I have of course checked that the page received in data variable is ALL of the code. It is correct. The missing tags are missing when displayed in the iframe.

(parent page, domain unknown to me as a API provider)

```
<body>
<iframe id="EMSNLframe" srcdoc="" seamless></iframe>

<script>
$("#EMSNLframe").load(function(){
  $.post("https://api.educationalmedia.se/API_displayNTNewsLetterMenu",
  {
  ResUID:"[secret code]",
  MenuLanguage:"English",
  PDFLanguage:"" // Blank for all languages, or state a language 
  },
  function(data,status){
    $("#EMSNLframe").contents().find("html").html(data); //<---- this is the line I need a solution for! If there is any.
  });
  $("#EMSNLframe").contents().find("head").append($("<style>  #EMSNLmenu{font-family:'Arial',sans-serif;font-size:12px}  </style>"));
});
</script>
</body>
```

Webpage received in data variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="https://data.educationalmedia.se/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<link href="https://data.educationalmedia.se/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script src="https://data.educationalmedia.se/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://data.educationalmedia.se/js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://data.educationalmedia.se/js/kendo.popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://data.educationalmedia.se/js/kendo.menu.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="EMSNLmenu">
<!--#4DHTML HTMLmenu_t-->  Don't mind this line of code. It is server side tags for data 
</div>

<script>
$("#EMSNLmenu").kendoMenu({
 animation: { open: { effects: "fadeIn" } },
 orientation: "vertical",
 closeOnClick: true,
 openOnClick: true,
 direction: "bottom right"
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: unless I'm mistaken, I don't think you can modify iframe content from outside of the iframe. You would need to use postMessage,ajax, etc. to communicate with the iframe and update content accordingly

Comment: I am not sure of the boundaries making changes to the iframe content, but you sure can. I have many times added styles or made other modifications. The difference this time is that I don't need to add some piece of content, but a full page including javascript and it must load as usually so that the javascript can take effect on the content.